# Error on import MySQLdb

Tags: python, import, mysql-python

i am using python 2.7.2 (windows 7) and i cant import MySQLdb, error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
import MySQLdb
File "C:\Python27\lib\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: No module named _mysql
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed the mysql binaries and not just the python client library? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a [Windows MSI installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/latest/download) on SourceForge, which eliminates the build step, which requires MS Visual Studio **2008** among other things.